# Working with ts/tsx files directly by using script type="module" in the web app (browser)

Tags: typescript, webpack, vite, esbuild, jsm

Using vite dev server allows me to use tsx/ts files directly (without packing and even transpiling!)

```
<script type="module" src="../client/main.tsx"></script>
```

Typescript files are transformed on the fly:
[image]

This is really fast and speeds up developent
Two questions:

1. Looks like this is only for development. Can I use it in production? (embed in server app)
2. Is it possible to achieve the same results using webpack (dev server)?

Answer (score 1):

Vite is a great framework for development. However, for production, it bundles the code with [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) to support older browsers. You can read more [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html). If you're using SSR, you need to create two separate builds. Vite will still modify the HTML on the fly on the server-side, but the JS will still be bundled. I haven't tried using ESM in production, but you should be able to serve your transpiled (but still ESM) source files statically after being built with something like [ESBuild](https://esbuild.github.io/). However, bundling can help with file size and request waterfall issues. Vite is mainly for the purpose of developer experience and satisfaction with a huge bonus on speed.

Webpack, however, is not built for this purpose. Webpack is solely a bundler, whereas Vite is a development framework. Webpack dev server watches for changes within your code and then re-bundles the files. Webpack is focused on large projects with many dependencies, whereas Vite is focused on modern concepts.